# What's the purpose of か in 自分に1年間頑張ったご褒美といいますか、プレゼントとして服をかいました。

Tags: grammar, particles

Encountered in this video at around the 0:35 mark. https://youtu.be/EtmZtv5vwvA

Full sentence: まだ11月で、クリスマスまで1ヶ月ほどありますが、自分に1年間頑張ったご褒美といいます**か**、プレゼントとして服をかいました。

I understand the sentence as "It's still November and around a month to christmas but I bought (myself) clothes as a present (so to say) as a reward for my efforts during the year." (Correct me if I'm wrong)

But I don't understand why the question marker か is used here.

Comment: My first thought was that the speaker is wondering about the topic, posing a question to themselves ("wouldn't it be nice..."), and expected to hear the tone confirm it. However, the kinda robotic way it is pronounced in the video foiled me, so I am not really sure.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/59687/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/46745/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30073/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11571/9831